# Problem with converting and comparing dates in c++

Tags: c++

I want to write a custom class DateAndTime to simplify work with dates in my project.
The problem is that I cannot compare the dates properly or I have a problem with converting the dates.

**My goal is:**

1. Create a DateAndTime from string
2. Create a DateAndTime as a current date
3. Compare 2 dates using the custom DateAndTime class

Please, help me :)

**This is my code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class DateAndTime
{
    private:
        const std::string dateTemplate = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M";
    public:
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
        time_t fullDate;
    public:
        DateAndTime(std::string dataString)
        {
             struct tm tm;
             strptime(dataString.c_str(), dateTemplate.c_str() ,&tm);
             year = 1900 + tm.tm_year;
             month = 1 + tm.tm_mon;
             day = tm.tm_mday;
             fullDate = mktime(&tm);
             cout << "Date from string: " << ctime(&fullDate) << endl;
        }
        DateAndTime()
        {
             time_t currentDate;
             struct tm * localDate;
             time (&currentDate);
             localDate = localtime (&currentDate);
             fullDate = currentDate;
             year = 1900 + localDate->tm_year;
             month = 1+ localDate->tm_mon;
             day = localDate->tm_mday;
             cout << "Current date: " << ctime(&fullDate) << endl;
        }
    public:
        std::string toString()
        {
            return std::to_string(year) + "-" + std::to_string(month) + "-" + std::to_string(day); 
        }
        int diffDays(DateAndTime data)
        {
           return difftime(data.fullDate, this->fullDate) / 86400;//devide by 1d in seconds
        }
};

int main()
{
    //Now
    DateAndTime d1;
    cout<< d1.year << endl;
    cout<< d1.month << endl;
    cout<< d1.day << endl;
    cout << d1.toString() << endl << endl;
         
    //Other
    string d = "2021-14-01 14:17:33";
    DateAndTime d2(d);
    cout<< d2.year << endl;
    cout<< d2.month << endl;
    cout<< d2.day << endl;
    cout<< d2.toString();
    
    cout << endl;
    
    cout << "Diff days: " << d1.diffDays(d2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
Current date: Thu Jan 14 14:40:18 2021
2021
1
14
2021-1-14
Date from string: Wed Mar 28 07:53:20 -26461971
2021
-314878271
32767
2021--314878271-32767
Diff days: -2147483648*
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template (`%Y-%m-%d %H:%M`) does not match your input (`2021-14-01 14:17:33`) and you are not checking errors.

Answer (score 0):

Best to completely initialize `struct tm tm;`  In C, its `struct tm tm = { 0 };`.  `strptime()` does not set every member of `tm` that is used by `mktime()`.

In OP's case `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"`: `.tm_isdst`, `.tm_sec` (maybe others) are not assigned nor prior initialized and can lead to erroneous results.